# android login with string response

Tags: java, android, httpresponse

i want to make a form login, if login unsuccessfull, it will give string response "2", i have try to make it, but i got an eror.
this is my asynctask:

```
public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        String strUser = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        String strPass = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        String strUrlMain="http://www.abc.co.id/a/bb/login.htm?u="+strUser+"&p="+strPass;
        String str2;

        public LoginAsyncTask(){
            this.strUrlMain=strUrlMain; 
            System.out.println(strUrlMain);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginProposal.this, "", "Mohon Tunggu, Sedang Melakukan Verifikasi");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result="";
            try {
                result=Connection.get(strUrlMain);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                result=" ";
                }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            if (!result.equals("")) {
                if(str2.equals("2"))
                {
                     Dialog.dismiss();
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginProposal.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Login Gagal");
                        builder.setMessage("User ID atau password salah.");
                     builder.setPositiveButton("Coba Kembali",
                             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             txtPassword.setText("");
                             txtPassword.findFocus();
                             btnLogin.setClickable(true);
                         }
                     });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Keluar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                   finish();
                               }
                           });
                        builder.create().show();
                }

                else{
                    Dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent slide2 = new Intent(LoginProposal.this, DataProposal.class);

                    startActivity(slide2);

        }
```

this is my connection method:

```
public class Connection {

    public static String get(String url) throws IOException
    {
        String apiResponse = "";
        try {
            String urlFix = url;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet post = new HttpGet(urlFix);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                throw new Exception("Got HTTP " + statusCode + " ("
                        + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase() + ')');
            }

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            if(entity != null)
            {

                //"iso-8859-1"
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                apiResponse = sb.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                apiResponse = "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return apiResponse;
    }
}
```

this is what my logcat say:

```
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at id.co.asjmsig.eproposal.LoginProposal$LoginAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginProposal.java:80)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at id.co.asjmsig.eproposal.LoginProposal$LoginAsyncTask.onPostExecute(LoginProposal.java:1)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
10-03 10:55:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(7561):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LoginProposal.java:80 is `if(str2.equals("2"))`, i don't know where is my fault, i hope somebody can help me to solve it, thank you

Comment: Your API response is 2 this not a valid JSON response. Pls change the response like this{"res":{"msg":"2"}}

Comment: you didnt assign value to str2.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a value to the `str2` variable. That is the mistake.

Comment: value str2 is return from web.

Comment: @AoyamaNanami and where is the place it is written to the variable `str2`?

Comment: Change it to should help `if (!result.equals("")) {
                if(result.equals("2"))`

Comment: @MaximEfimov str2 is a String to handle response from server, i have assign str2 as String

Comment: @AoyamaNanami `String str2` is the definition, not assignment. You need to write somewhere `str2 = "response"` or `str2 = DataLoader.load()`. Then str2 would contain some data. After just `String str2` str2 is `null`.

Comment: @AoyamaNanami I can't implement app's logic for you as I don't understand what `str2` must represent. I gave a few examples in the previous comment. Please, check the logic - you create the variable `str2`, never assign a value to it, then try to use it. There is a mistake somwhere because it just doesn't make any sence. If you want to do "something" with "some" object you should build or get or somehow obtain the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this way
String str2="";
```